# UML In ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: software-recommendation, uml

So i want start UML With My Ubuntu 13.10. Please I need Help What I need First to Start On Ubuntu To Make UML? Tools and Utilities I Needed To Learn And Develop both In Ubuntu Platform.

Comment: Please read this answers from our forum: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9405/what-uml-tools-are-available

Answer (score 0):

use dia here's a link where you can find documentation and description
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dia